# Property outFiles is not allowed in vs code's launch.json

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug typescript in vs code. As far as I researched, you need to set the outfiles property in th launch.config for vs code to map a breakpoint that you have set in a TypeScript file from the compiled .js file, as specified [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/69161).

When I try to set mine, I get this error:

[image]

I found nothing about this error in google, and as this settings is needed for the typescript debugger to work, as indicated also in the [vs code documentation](https://vscode-eastus.azurewebsites.net/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit:

launch.json:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc",
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
    "outDir": "src/ts-built",
    "rootDir": "src"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `"outFiles" : true` for a chrome debug config

If you are looking to debug your typescript code, you need to make sure you have set your ts compiler to generate source maps.

Make sure you have these two settings in your `tsconfig` file.

```js
//TSCONFIG SETTINGS
"inlineSourceMap": true /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */,
"inlineSources": true /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */,
```

and if you already have `"sourceMap": true,` in your `tsconfig` you need to remove it if you want to use `"inlineSourceMap": true` NOT FROM LAUNCH.JSON!

These settings will generate inline source maps for your code.

In the end your launch.config should look something like this

```js
{
  "name": "Launch Chrome",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/wwwroot",
  "sourceMaps": true // this is is the important setting. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I followed your instructions but if I set a breakpoint in the .js it breaks there, but not in the .ts that is what I want. I update my tsconfig and launch.json in the question

Comment: I meant that it didnt not break when the breakpoint is set of course, but thanks

Comment: my bad sorry, let me check once

Comment: Hey, I checked with a demo project, here and it seems to be working here  https://i.imgur.com/Vq5HvLg.gifv  here are the files https://gofile.io/d/5dtpy1 if you want to cross check

Comment: If still not working, can you provide more details on the type of project, your folder structure and the html files you are using the script in?

Comment: Its working now. The problem was that I am using webpack in my project, and that needs to be configured to deal with typescript. I did that accoding to the webpack docs and worked https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/

Comment: Anyhow I find your sample project so useful to have a simple depart project to check the options that work, so thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: I have 2 small more issues know, 1.- I have the compilation prebuilfd task so that the typescript files are compiled every time. The terminal changes and I would like the terminal to go back to the node teminal when the pre task is completed automatically. Also, the breapoints do not behave perfectly. I mean that I cant stop for example in some specific conts variable I define, and If I can, the variable value is not yet available in the watch, or when you hover, until you step down some lines down...I will try to get that fix. Any comments are much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: the brakpoint behaviour in your project is good though....

Comment: I spent some hours trying to solve this, so here you go in case you can and would not mindd to help me. Thanks in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62485740/debugger-breakpoint-incorrect-line-webpack-configuration-typescript

Comment: Welcome! im on mobile  but ill try to help