# Debugger breakpoint incorrect line. Webpack configuration typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, source-maps

I finally got typescript working in my project, but the breakpoints do not stop in the correct line, and the variable values are not available until you step into some more lines of code in the step by step execution. There seems to be some ttype if mismatch in the source map.
I tried to solve this adding tje SourceMapDevToolPlugin to the webpack config file as intructed [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7172).
But doesn't solve the problem.

Below screenshots of what I mean:

[image]

myString is undefine, although the line has supposedly beed executed.

[image]

After it jumps directly to the function (not to the `const myNumber = myFunc(5);` where the function is called) and the value of the string is availabe, so this is so weird.

Below my webpack config, launch.json and tsconfig.

webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
// const SourceMapDevToolPlugin = require('');

const modulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const srcPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const outputPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

const basename = process.env.BASENAME || '/';
const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development';

module.exports = {
  mode,
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000,
    stats: 'minimal',
  },
  entry: [
    path.join(srcPath, 'index.css'),
    path.join(srcPath, './trial.ts'),
  ],
  output: {
    path: outputPath,
    publicPath: basename,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': srcPath,
    },
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.js', '.json'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...(mode === 'development' ? [
        {
          test: /\.(js)$/,
          enforce: 'pre',
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          options: {
            emitWarning: true,
          },
          include: srcPath,
          exclude: modulesPath,
        },
      ] : []),
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            ['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false }],
          ],
        },
        include: srcPath,
        exclude: modulesPath,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: { sourceMap: true },
          },
        ],
        include: [srcPath, modulesPath],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(vert|frag)$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        include: srcPath,
        exclude: modulesPath,
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: modulesPath,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(srcPath, 'index.ejs'),
      title: 'WebGL boilerplate',
      favicon: './favicon.ico',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    ...(mode !== 'production' ? [
      new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        moduleFilenameTemplate: (info) => (
          `file:///${info.absoluteResourcePath}`
        ),
      }),
    ] : []),
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      filename: null,
      exclude: [/node_modules/],
      test: /\.ts($|\?)/i,
    }),
  ],
};
```

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
            // "preLaunchTask": "tsc",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "sourceMapPathOverrides":{
                "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///*": "*",
                "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*",
                "meteor://app/*": "${webRoot}/*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "inlineSourceMap": true,                  /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    "inlineSources": true,                    /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
    "outDir": "./src/ts-built/",
    "rootDir": "./src/"
  }
}
```

Note that `// "preLaunchTask": "tsc";` is commented. That is the prelaunch task that compiles the typescript files, however, onced I configured webpack and tsc to work with the `'inline-source-map'` mode, even the .js compiled file the prelaunchtask commented, the app will run, with brakpoints in the typescript file (with weird behaviour an line mismatch).

So I dont know what I am missing in the inline-source-map mode configuration, or if It should be used the normal `'souceMAps': true` mode, where sourcemaps are generated on the typescript files compilation.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you sure, the code is compiling everytime since you've comment the `tsc` task? because sourcemaps are added by `tsc`

Comment: even If I uncomment the code, the same happens. Why I explained the commented line thing is because If I comment that line, and remove the .js compiled file, the app runs and breakpoint hits anyway, I think due to the inline-source-map config. I think its created somewhere or someway else, bacause In that case I cannot see any .js file nad .map file generated, but, the brakpoint hits anyhow, but not properly though

Comment: can you check this solution https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6044#issuecomment-490719119

Comment: I added sourceMap: true wherever I could in the options webpackConfig  as stated in the repo, running 1 by 1 everytime I added that for each of the rules sections (I mean adding changes 1 by one te have clear where the problem came from if the issue fixed). Does not fix the problem. I also tried toggling MiniCssExtractPlugin sourmap option to true and false in case that could have saom influence...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed my tsconfig to `SourMaps:true;` mode and that fixed the issue.
Below the corrected tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    //"inlineSourceMap": true,                  /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    //"inlineSources": true,                    /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */
    "sourceMap": true,
    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
    "outDir": "./src/ts-built",
    "rootDir": "./src"
  }
}
```

As far as I researched I think I get how the `"sourceMap": true` mode works. The .map generated file by the tsc compiler is used to map the compiled .js to the .ts file on debugging. It seems that the `//"inlineSourceMap": true,` and `//"inlineSources": true,` get the source map from the text generated at the end of the .js file instead of the separted .map file, and that mode is the one I expected to work as the name of the devtool in the webpack config is `'inline-source-map'`. I don't know if both modes can be used in webpack, as long as one of the two works that is fine. However if only the NO inline mode works, and the devtool name is `'inline-source-map'`, I find that quite misleading.

Thanks for any explanatory comments on this regard.

Comment: Nice! Yes, if you are using a complex project like this, you need to make sure all your settings are uniform throughout all your stack! You can't use inline somewhere and then tell something else to use .map files  :D

Comment: Sure! That I was saying that the devtool: 'inline-source-map' name is quite misleading...https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/ In the docs itself it says to include the devtool: 'inline-source-map' + the "sourceMap": true, in the tsconfig, which works, but I find the devtool name quite misleading. Thanks for your comments and help!

Comment: `devtools: "source-map" + "sourceMap": true` works too. I wonder why. Maybe it doesn't matter whether it's source map files or inline source maps in Webpack as long as the TypeScript compiler is generating the right source maps.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me when I develop grafana-plugin. Not sure if there's anything special there. Struggled for few days, finally find this bug: https://github.com/swc-project/jest/issues/61

So `sourceMap=true` is not enough, but we have to use `inlineSourceMap` instead. And we have to change the following two files at the same time to make it works:

1. In `.config/jest.config.js`: `change sourceMaps: "inline"` from `sourceMaps: true`
2. In `.config/tsconfig.json`: add `"inlineSourceMap": true` for `compilerOptions`